# How do I handle a back-button press in a (DelphiXE 6) Android app?

Tags: android, delphi, back-button, delphi-xe6

How can I make my Android app react to the back-button from Delphi XE6?

```
    uses
  FMX.Platform, FMX.VirtualKeyboard;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = vkHardwareBack then
  begin
     // Back button pressed...
        Key := 0;
  end;
end;
```

**The code above does not work**

Comment: Are you use TWebBrowser on that form ? ?

Comment: The problem was due to the following reason FMX.Helpers.Android;